# How do I get absolute acceleration in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to define a coordinate system when unity starts based on the phone, but then have that stay constant forever on after, so that when I then measure acceleration, it disregards how the phone is tilted (where it is facing) and instead just measures how it is moved.  Is there an api for this?  The normal Input.acceleration or gyro doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Gyroscope.userAcceleration;` is the possible solution. It measures the acceleration that user provides to the device i.e, it discards the effect of gravity.

Comment: Yes, but it still counts rotational acceleration.  I want to set the direction my phone is facing to be, say, x at the start, and then have that be x forever, even if I make my phone face 90 degrees to the right, or anywhere else.  I've been testing and found that the direction your phone is facing is always set to be a certain axis, instead of it being the way I need it to (constant/absolute).  I've searched for an easy API, but couldn't find it.  I now know sort of how to make it, but it would have been much nicer to not have to put in so much work for something seemingly so simple...